# Programmatically add points to Map Layer on Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql-server, dictionary, points, shapefile, reportbuilder

So, I have a .shp map from a certain region of the world. I also have a dataset with information of several stations that I want to show over this map. On this dataset I have several fields, but two with latitude and longitude. I have to create one point on the map for each row of this dataset, using the latitude and longitude provided. Everything that I could do so far was creating a new report, inserting the map from the shapefile and adding a Point Layer to it, but after this I can't figure out what I have to do to show the points based on the coordinates. Do you guys have any advice of what I have to do now?

Thanks a lot for your attention.

PS: I'm using Report Builder 3.0 and a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.